# use the tell application statement with other then application name

Tags: applescript, filemaker

I have one particular problem with file maker pro.
On the mac there are both FMP11 and FMP12 installed.
I have a script which makes FMP open a doc and do some processing.
The script worked so far OK but the new is that I have both FMP11 and FMP12 docs mixed. So I have to open appropriate FMP to do the job.
The trouble is that they are both registered with the same name in the AppleScript Application listing, so if I "tell application File Maker Pro Advanced", it does not strictly define to which one am I telling.
I tried to trick the problem by quitting all FMPs and then open a FMP11 or FM12 dummy document through Finder, this will start the appropriate FMP version, but then when I want to switch to it with activate, or I use the tell for the first time after that, if the one which is open is FMP11 all works fine, if the FMP12 is open, the tell statement will open the FMP11.
The strangest thing of all is that in another simplified version of the script, it works fine.

So my question is: is there any other way of using the tell application then with the registered Name of the application?

I tried to get the properties for both FMP11 and FMP12 and here is the result:

***FMP11**

get properties of application process "FileMaker Pro"
        --> {enabled:missing value, unix id:63125, file:alias "MACHD:Applications:FileMaker Pro 11 Advanced:FileMaker Pro Advanced.app:", creator type:"FMP7", subrole:missing value, entire contents:{}, selected:missing value, application file:alias "MACHD:Applications:FileMaker Pro 11 Advanced:FileMaker Pro Advanced.app:", orientation:missing value, role:"AXApplication", accepts high level events:true, file type:"APPL", value:missing value, position:missing value, id:25741451, **displayed name:"FileMaker Pro Advanced"**, name:"FileMaker Pro", class:application process, background only:false, frontmost:false, size:missing value, visible:true, Classic:false, role description:"application", maximum value:missing value, architecture:"i386", partition space used:0, **short name:"FileMaker Pro Advanced"**, focused:missing value, minimum value:missing value, help:missing value, **title:"FileMaker Pro Advanced"**, accepts remote events:false, description:"application", total partition size:0, accessibility description:missing value, has scripting terminology:true, bundle identifier:"com.filemaker.client.advanced"}

**FMP12**

get properties of application process "FileMaker Pro"
        --> {enabled:missing value, unix id:63199, file:alias "MACHD:Applications:FileMaker Pro 12 Advanced:FileMaker Pro Advanced.app:", creator type:"FM12", subrole:missing value, entire contents:{}, selected:missing value, application file:alias "MACHD:Applications:FileMaker Pro 12 Advanced:FileMaker Pro Advanced.app:", orientation:missing value, role:"AXApplication", accepts high level events:true, file type:"APPL", value:missing value, position:missing value, id:25753742, displayed name:"FileMaker Pro Advanced", name:"FileMaker Pro", class:application process, background only:false, frontmost:false, size:missing value, visible:true, Classic:false, role description:"application", maximum value:missing value, architecture:"i386", partition space used:0, short name:"FileMaker Pro Advanced", focused:missing value, minimum value:missing value, help:missing value, title:"FileMaker Pro Advanced", accepts remote events:false, description:"application", total partition size:0, accessibility description:missing value, has scripting terminology:true, bundle identifier:"com.filemaker.client.advanced12"}*

So it seems that the string appearing in Dictionary of the Apple Script Editor is the displayed name, short name or title propery but they are same for both apps.

So how can I open and tell to the appropriate FMP version, any idea?

Comment: I just found one post which is discussing something very close to my problem, but I'm not sure if it answers, I have to test, here is the link http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24569

Comment: Just got the answer on another forum

use the bundle identifier in conjunction with application id

for FMP 11 tell application id "com.filemaker.client.advanced"

for FMP 12 tell application id "com.filemaker.client.advanced12"

@ http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=151957#p151957

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tell application id` form with the creator code or bundle ID.

For example, try this:

```
tell application id "FMP7"
    activate
end tell
```

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted?  I use this form all the time, since I have a few applications where I keep multiple versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
do shell script "open -b 'com.filemaker.client.advanced12'"
tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
    properties
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks, I just got the answer, see the comment to my answer, it goes it the same direction but uses purely applescript which is better in my case because later in the code I have to "tell" again, and the "do shell" does not put me in a tell, but thanks anyway

Comment: I like Stefan's solution better too.

Answer (score 0):

set appName to id of current application as string

Comment: Too short an answer to be useful.